# locale-specific to_lower problems with boost locale

Tags: c++, utf-8, icu, boost-locale

I'm experimenting with boost::locale::to_upper to do locale-specific upper-casing as per the boost-locale page http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html

The text indicates that I should be able to use boost::locale::to_upper on 'grüßEN' and get the result 'GRÜSSEN' - which is the correct locale-specific uppercase version (So I believe).

In my test version, I'm getting 'GRÜßEN' and not 'GRÜSSEN'.

My test code looks like this (i'm using utf8cpp to check my string is actually utf8):

```
                boost::locale::generator gen;                                    
                std::locale loc= gen("de_DE.UTF-8");  

                std::locale::global(loc); 
                cout.imbue(loc);

                string s = "grüßEN"; 
                if (utf8::is_valid(s.begin(), s.end())){
                    std::cout << s << " U= "<< boost::locale::to_upper(s) << std::endl;
                }
```

This is on OSX (10.7.4) using Xcode (4.1). I have installed ICU (49_1_2) with the suggested options of -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1. ICU is in /usr/local/include/unicode and the libraries in /usr/local/lib/libicu*.*

I built boost::locale from the 1_48 kit like this:

```
./bjam boost.locale.iconv=off -sICU_PATH=/usr/local --with-locale stage
```

and when building it reports:

```
Performing configuration checks

- icu                      : yes

Component configuration:

 - chrono                   : not building
- date_time                : not building
- exception                : not building
- filesystem               : not building
- graph                    : not building
- graph_parallel           : not building
- iostreams                : not building
- locale                   : building
- math                     : not building
- mpi                      : not building
- program_options          : not building
- python                   : not building
- random                   : not building
- regex                    : not building
- serialization            : not building
- signals                  : not building
- system                   : not building
- test                     : not building
- thread                   : not building
- timer                    : not building
- wave                     : not building

...patience...
...patience...
...found 1850 targets...
...updating 25 targets...
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-    off/threading-multi/encoding/codepage.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/boundary.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/codecvt.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/collator.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/conversion.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/date_time.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/formatter.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/icu_backend.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/numeric.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/icu/time_zone.o
darwin.link.dll bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/threading-multi/libboost_locale.dylib
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_locale.dylib    
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv- off/link-static/threading-multi/encoding/codepage.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/boundary.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/codecvt.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/collator.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/conversion.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/date_time.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/formatter.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/icu_backend.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/numeric.o
darwin.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/time_zone.o
darwin.archive bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_locale.a
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (codecvt.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-  static/threading-multi/std/codecvt.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin- 4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/codecvt.o (due to use  of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (codecvt.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/codecvt.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/codecvt.o (due to use of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (collate.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/std/collate.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/collate.o (due to use of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (converter.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/std/converter.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/converter.o (due to use of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (date_time.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/date_time.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/shared/date_time.o (due to use of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (numeric.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/icu/numeric.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/numeric.o (due to use of basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
/usr/bin/libtool: warning same member name (numeric.o) in output file used for input files: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/posix/numeric.o and: bin.v2/libs/locale/build/darwin-4.2.1/release/boost.locale.iconv-off/link-static/threading-multi/std/numeric.o (due to use of  basename, truncation, blank padding or duplicate input files)
common.copy stage/lib/libboost_locale.a
...updated 25 targets...
```

According to https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6424, the warnings can be ignored (or does anyone know better?)
I copy the built libs from stage/libs to /usr/local/libs.

So as far as I can tell it is correctly built against ICU. My test code does require me to link against libiconv - I would have thought that wouldn't be necessary as I turned off icon in the build?

Can anyone provide me some insight into what is going on/what I have done wrong and why I don't get the expected behaviour as documented - or at least some things to try?

cheers

Chris

Comment: Works for me (that is, I'm getting the correct GRÜSSEN result) on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTE with gcc-4.4.3 and boost-1.49. Turkish I/İ is OK too. I don't have system-wide German or Turkish locales installed.

Answer (score 0):

so XCODE crashed on me (as it often seems to do), and once I re-launched it, and re-built the project, it asks for the ICU libraries and no longer needs the iconv library - i.e. as expected. 
I'm going to chalk that one down to XCODE voodoo I think. I'll leave the question as it does at least cover how to build boost locale with ICU on OSX.